# Node js Cannot GET /api/ When requesting on my live host

Tags: node.js, express, npm, cpanel

I have taken about 2days to research on this and i have come across several answers but it doesn't still solve my problem.

I have this api app which i built with nodejs and express js,
when I listen to it on the main port from a port like `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, it returns the right response of **hello world**, but when i tried to host it to my cpanel following this steps here [How to Host a Node.JS Application With cPanel](https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-host-a-node-js-application-with-cpanel/) and visit `http:// mysite.com/api` same with `(https:// mysite.com/api)` it returns the error `Cannot GET /api/`

I don't know what else to do, i will really appreciate any help.

**N/B:** my server is running node version 16.13.1 and express version 4.17.2

**here is my app.js code**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");


const app = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// database
const db = require("./app/models");
const Role = db.role;

db.sequelize.sync();

// simple route
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello World." });
  console.log(res);
});

// routes
require('./app/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./app/routes/user.routes')(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

**Here is my package json code**

```
{
  "name": "node-js-jwt-auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js Demo for JWT Authentication",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "set HOST=localhost&& set PORT=8080&& node app.js",
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&& node app.js",
    "prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&& node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node.js",
    "jwt",
    "authentication",
    "express",
    "mysql"
  ],
  "author": "bezkoder",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "joi": "^17.5.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "keygenerator": "^1.0.4",
    "mailgen": "^2.0.16",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "sequelize": "^5.22.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you change the cors origin after host application in cPanel?

Comment: Not at all, could that be my problem?

Comment: Maybe yes. Also you can try port 3000 as cPanel doc noted.

Comment: not still working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright After much check, I was able to solve my problem.

The error was from the htaccess file in my root folder of public_html.

It was resolved automatically after moving the project to a separate folder outside the public_html..

Thanks Alot for everyone that contributed

Answer (score 0):

Your simple route is a POST request route:

here:

```js
// simple route
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello World." });
  console.log(res);
});
```

If you open a given URL in the browser it makes a GET request to your app and the given route. If there is only a POST route it won't do anything.

So I think you can just change the simple route to:

```js
// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello World." });
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: even when using a GET route, its same.... additionally, i am using postman api for testing